# Improving mongo query Performance(using Sub query )

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Two documents can have same `IMAGE_CONTENT_INSTANCE_HANDLE` and state can be `BOOKED` or `RELEASED` 
but I want all image instances handles which are only `RELEASED` state, 
Currently I am doing this by firing two queries it introduced performance issues.

```
{ 
    "state" : "RELEASED"
}
```

with projection { "imageContentInstance.handle" : 1}

i am iterating through the result which is coming out from this query 
and firing another query as below and excluding the handles which are also in BOOKED state from adding to the list.So i gets handles only in the RELEASED state

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
ICI ici = objectMapper.readValue(result, ICI_COLLECTION_TYPE_REF);
    String result = JSON.serialize(cursor.next());
    try {
        queryDocument =  { "imageContentInstance.handle" : ici.getImageContentInstance().getHandle() , "state" : "BOOKED"}
        Document bookedDoc = iciDAO.findOne(queryDocument);
        if (null != bookedDoc)
            LOGGER.debug("Calling continue and skipping booked state ");
        continue;
    }
    iciHandles.add(ici.getImageContentInstance().getHandle().toString());
    LOGGER.debug("ImageInstanceHandle is added to the lisr and the lise is "+iciHandles.size());
}
```

I want to achieve this in a single mongo query as an example query written in sql to increase performance .I really appreciate your comments .

```
SELECT *
FROM ici i
WHERE i.state = 'RELEASED'
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM ici ic WHERE ic.handle = i.handle AND ic.state = 'BOOKED'
  );
```

example :
Suppose the documents are as below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c9f524fa8cd6a517cf5ddf"),
    "imageContentInstance" : {
        "handle" : "ICI:1234",
        "key" : null,
        }
    "instanceHandle" : "LCI:RNBM12",
    "state" : "BOOKED",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c9f524fa8cd6a517cf5ddf"),
    "imageContentInstance" : {
        "handle" : "ICI:1234",
        "key" : null,
        }
    "instanceHandle" : "LCI:RNBM13",
    "state" : "RELEASED",
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c9f524fa8cd6a517cf5ddf"),
    "imageContentInstance" : {
        "handle" : "ICI:456",
        "key" : null,
        }
    "instanceHandle" : "LCI:RNBM14",
    "state" : "RELEASED"
}
```

My query should return the handle of the last document alone .ie, document with the status only with the RELEASED status .i am stuck, I really appreciate your ideas to improve this.

Answer (score 1):

From Your question,i understand that you want all  state ='Released' ans state!= 'BOOKED' which i think you have written little incorrect.

MongoDB query:

```
db.inventory.find({'state' : 'RELEASED'}})
```

Also go through [mognodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)
I hope it will help.I am also new to mongodb,if there is an error please make it correct.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs .Suppose the documents are as below  

document1 --> handle : 1234 
        state : Booked 
     
document2 --> handle : 1234
     state : RELEASED 
     
document3 --> handle : 4567
   state: RELEASED 
   
I want to fetch only document 3 . However your query fetches document2 also which i dont want .

Comment: db.inventory.distinct( "item.handle", { status: "RELEASED" } );  
I hope it will do the trick for you .Please upvote if it helps.

Comment: Sorry :) . It did not work . Since distinct function applied  on handle , it fetch one distinct record with RELEASED status . But There should not be any document with this handle with the BOOKED status then only i have fetch the record .